# Android progressBar not showing

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a progressbar that is supposed to run in an AsyncTask , but it is not appearing, although the task runs

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splashportrait">
<ProgressBar android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:paddingBottom="450dip"
    android:layout_width="200dip" android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"></ProgressBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE:

```
ProgressBar diagProgress;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    diagProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    DiagnosticsTask diag = new DiagnosticsTask();
    diag.execute();

  /**rest of class ommitted here**/
}

private class DiagnosticsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    //Show spinner
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //dialog.setMessage("Loading corresponding destinations...");
        //dialog.show();
        diagProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        diagProgress.showContextMenu();
        Log.e("AsyncStatus", "spinner shown");
    }
 /*other parts of the thread ommitted here*/

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this replace your ProgressBar with the one below.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    />
```

Let me know if it works, I would explain the rationale.

Rationale:
Now I am putting your code below for ProgressBar

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:paddingBottom="450dip"
    />
```

RelativeLayout allows you Z-ordering. So since you needed ProgressBar on top you need not do the kind of manipulations you are doing.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This sets the Progress Bar at the botton of the layout:

```
android:paddingBottom="450dip" android:layout_width="200dip" android:layout_height="200dip"
```

All the three values here are absolute which is a strict no-no as far as Android is concerned. Most Likely your paddingBottom was pushing your ProgressBar out of View. As your padding is greater than the actual width/height of the control

As a thumb rule always use relative values for it to work on all the devices and form factors.

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: this works, the rationale? it appears that it can't be seen on a white background, thanks

Comment: check the rationale and let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: Thanks CQM for the white background comment (face palm)

Answer (score 43):

I had that issue when I forgot to turn on animations after testing xD

Comment: I got the same problem. When you do UI testing on android you have to disable animations, so weirds UI behaviours appear (like progressbar not showing at all) ! This is not a bad answer as it leads me to the right direction :)

Comment: Same happened to me. Check on your android device: Settings > Development  > Anything regarding animation

Comment: After wasting hours dealing with progressBar, I've now realized that I had to activate animations on my phone, thanks!

Comment: Oh my, I turned animations off while using Espresso for UI testing. This answer was the clue to remember. Thanks.

Comment: Omg! I never thought about it. Anyway thanks.This is a good answer.

Comment: how do you turn on animations?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to execute your task?

```
  ...
  diagProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
  new DiagnosticsTask().execute();


  ....
```

Comment: the task runs, I mentioned that, I'll edit my code snippet to show that part

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue when I make visibility gone and visible instant of gone make invisible in my case working invisible and visible

```
private fun hideShowProgressBar(isShowProgress:Boolean){
    if(isShowProgress){
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tvSetProgress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        tvSetProgress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I solved it by going into themes.xml and undoing the changes I made to the primary brand colors.

The progress bar appeared when I changed it back to these colors:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
```