# progressbar not showing on start up

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have the following set up according to some book. But still fail to see the progress bar when the app is loaded.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText et;
private ImageView iv;
private ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            //String input = et.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, input,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //**
            //pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:text="This is a text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#00ff00"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type sth here :)"
    android:maxLines="2"

    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/rose"
    />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I referenced this link: [Android progressBar not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450602/android-progressbar-not-showing) but still doesn't work in my case...the bar just simply does not show up...

Comment: strange. it should be "</LinearLayout>" at the end of xml file, I tried to add to above but it somehow does not show up.

Comment: ah...why down-vote le?? so discouraging...I think this question helps, as it's unique enough to differentiate it from the same kind...StackOverflow should really have stricter control on downvoting people, say, like reason when you downvote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root layout is LinearLayout .`android:layout_centerInParent` not an attribute for Linearlayout's child. So If you want to show 'ProgressBar' in center its better to use a Relative layout as parent.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is a text"
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Type sth here :)"
            android:maxLines="2"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/rose" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it works!! Great thanks! Even though it did not work when I was not using "android:layout_centerInParent". But this solution works and it's wise to stick to this. Great thanks @ADM, you solved my headache!

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is that you turn off animation in  developer options. 
I use your layout file in my test project. The progress bar show up and it works normally.
Turn off animation make the ProgressBar not visible.

Comment: I've turned on all animation-related functionalities on my Samsung phone, but it did not work for me. Or, do you mean there's some animation features I have to turn on in the android studio?